# nothing happens when i use script tag in ejs

Tags: javascript, ejs

I'm creating a simple discord bot panel, I wanted to do not have to click the submit button, unfortunately the `<select onchange="this.form.submit()"></select>` does not work, the same `console.log()` or such a simple function as `document.getElementById("").innerHTML = "text";`

My file:

```xml
<head>
    <title><%=bot.user.username%></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/assets/css/main.css" />
    <noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/assets/css/noscript.css" /></noscript>
</head>
<form method="post">
  <select style="float: right" name="lang" id="slct" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <option selected hidden value="no-change">LANGUAGE</option>
    <optgroup style="color: #99AAB5" label="finished">
    <option style="color: #7289DA" value="en">English</option>
    <option style="color: #7289DA" value="pl">Polish</option>
    <optgroup style="color: #99AAB5" label="beta">
    <option style="color: #7289DA" value="fr">France</option>
  </select>
  </form>
```

Tested code:

```js
<p id="test">Not changed</p>
<script>
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "Changed";
</script>
```

Render file:

```js
const dataDir = path.resolve(`${process.cwd()}${path.sep}dashboard`);
const templateDir = path.resolve(`${dataDir}${path.sep}page`);

const renderTemplate = (res, req, template, data = {}) => {
    const baseData = {
      bot: client,
      path: req.path,
      user: req.isAuthenticated() ? req.user : null
    };
    res.render(path.resolve(`${templateDir}${path.sep}${template}`), Object.assign(baseData, data));
  };

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    const duration = moment.duration(client.uptime).format(" D[d], H[h], m[m], s[s]");
    const members = client.guilds.cache.reduce((p, c) => p + c.memberCount, 0);
    const textChannels = client.channels.cache.filter(c => c.type === "text").size;
    const voiceChannels = client.channels.cache.filter(c => c.type === "voice").size;
    const guilds = client.guilds.cache.size;
    renderTemplate(res, req, "index.ejs", {
      stats: {
        servers: guilds,
        members: members,
        text: textChannels,
        voice: voiceChannels,
        uptime: duration,
        memoryUsage: (process.memoryUsage().heapUsed / 1024 / 1024).toFixed(2),
        dVersion: Discord.version,
        nVersion: process.version
      }
    });
  });
```

I also tested using `window.onload` function, could someone help?

Comment: Unrelated tip: every ``path.resolve(`${a}${path.sep}${b}`)`` can be written `path.join(a, b)`.

Comment: Where do you handle the post?

Comment: Check your browser’s developer tools. Does the document tree look right, HTML-wise? Are there any errors in the console, maybe relating to Content-Security-Policy?

Comment: @Ry- Yes, the problem is there Content-Security-Policy

Comment: Okay. Where are you using this that‘s adding a Content-Security-Policy (or are you adding it?), and what is the policy? (Use the Network panel to see the Content-Security-Policy header on the response to the request for the document. Or it might say in the error message.)

Comment: @Ry- "Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src-attr 'none'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

ListPicker._handleMouseUp"

I don't know where or what to add